# compact invertible of nonlinear pde with cubic term

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with smooth boudary, and consider the following nonlinear equation:
$$
Au=-\Delta u+cu+u^3=f,\quad \textrm{in}\, \Omega,
$$ 
and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Since $A$ is a maximal monotone operator with domain $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap L^6(\Omega)$, we know from $A^{-1}$ is well-defined and bounded. I am wondering whether I can show $A^{-1}:f\in L^2\to u_f\in H_0^1$ is compact?

---

What I have tried:

Consider $\{f_n\}$ be bounded sequence in $L^2$, we have $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2$, and I aim to show $u_n=u_{f_n}\to u_f$ in $H_0^1$.

The weak formulation gives me that
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u_n\nabla \phi+c\int_\Omega  u_n \phi+\int_\Omega  u_n^3 \phi=\int_\Omega f_n \phi,\quad \phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap L^6, \tag{1}
$$
set $\phi=u_n$ implies $|\nabla u_n|_{L^2}\le |f_n|_{L^2}$, and hence Poincare inequality implies $|u_n|_{H_0^1}$ and $|u_n|_{L^6}$ are bounded. Hence $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $H_0^1$ and $u_n\rightharpoonup u'$ in $L^6$.

In order to pass $n\to \infty$ in $(1)$, I need to show 
$$
\int_\Omega  u_n^3 \phi\to \int_\Omega  u^3 \phi,
$$
however I am not sure how to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sobolev embedding theorem together with Rellich-Kondrachov shows that
the embedding $H_0^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ is compact for all $p < 6$. Thus, $u_n^3 \to u^3$ in $L^{p/3}(\Omega)$ for all $p < 6$ and $\{u_n^3\}$ is bounded in $L^6(\Omega)$. This shows that $u_n^3 \rightharpoonup u^3$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: I understand $\{u^3\}$ is bounded implies that $u^3$ weakly converges in $L^2(\Omega)$ to some limit. May I know how to use the strong convergence in $L^p(\Omega)$, $p<2$ to argue the limit is $u^3$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If $w_n \rightharpoonup w$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ and $w_n \to v$ in $L^q(\Omega)$, you have $w = v$.